# JQuery: Setting CSS gradient isn't working

Tags: jquery, css, gradient, linear-gradients

### [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/x22Zh/2/)

I'm trying to set the background of an element to a gradient, however it's not setting. It's adding `style=""` to markup and it works when I put the code directly into firebug (I'm using Firefox). Any idea why it's not working or how I can get it to work?

```
$('main > article').each(function (index) {
    var bg = $(this).css('background-color');
    var nextbg = $(this).next().css('background-color');
    if ($(this).next().length && nextbg != bg) {
        $(this).css('background', 'linear-gradient(to bottom, ' + bg + ' 0%, ' + nextbg + ' 100%);');
        console.log('linear-gradient(to bottom, ' + bg + ' 0%, ' + nextbg + ' 100%);');
        console.log('------------');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the ";" at the end of your css

```
('main > article').each(function (index) {
    var bg = $(this).css('background-color');
    var nextbg = $(this).next().css('background-color');
    if ($(this).next().length && nextbg != bg) {
        $(this).css('background', 'linear-gradient(to bottom, ' + bg + ' 0%, ' + nextbg + ' 100%)');
        console.log('linear-gradient(to bottom, ' + bg + ' 0%, ' + nextbg + ' 100%);');
        console.log('------------');
    }
});
```

Comment: *facepalm* - thanks! Knew it must be something daft! xD